# Header DIV disappears on resize in Safari but works in Firefox and Safari Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I've had this issue with my header. My site is adaptive and when it reaches tablet size and less the navigation turns into a drop down box. When I resize the window in Firefox it degrades nicely, but in Safari, when it reaches the switch the whole header disappears. I've been toiling with it and discovered that when I removed the slider or set the sliders display to "none" it works. When the slider is there I can't tell if the header div is behind the slider or just disappeared all together.

What in gods name is going on here?

Here's the site.   http://www.benstephan.com/html

Comment: I tracked it down to the following: remove rsWebkit3d from #full-width-slider and remove the -webkit-transform on the .rsContainer inside it.  I couldn't track down what the rsWebkit3d class was doing in the web dev tools but hopefully that gets you started.

Comment: I tried it you in Safari 6.0.2 and it works fine. Shows the same result as the FF

Comment: Works also fine for me in Safari 6.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Your site works just fine in firefox, chrome and in safari too (tested with version 5.17). Probably you need to update safari then test. btw cool site.